# Svg:hover on two paths at once

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying a basic hover on an SVG which has two paths but I want both of these to be affected by the hover. When I try it, the hover works on each path individually.

http://jsfiddle.net/mexicanbandit/aLs36j4c/

```
path:hover {
    fill: rgb(230, 100, 100);
}
```

Just applied the hover to the path. I tried applying a class to each and applying the hover to that but it still had the same results.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the selector `svg:hover path` and change the color of the `path`s when hovering over the parent, `svg` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rt9u5mgh/)

```
svg:hover path {
    fill: rgb(230, 100, 100);
}
```

---

As [Duopixel mentions below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459858/svghover-on-two-paths-at-once/28459891#comment45246741_28459891), if you have mutliple paths within the `svg`, you can wrap the desired `path`s in order to target them.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6m8pd83q/)

For instance:

```
svg .arrows:hover path {
    fill: rgb(230, 100, 100);
}
```

```
<g class="arrows">
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="#C8C7C7" d="M7.333,22.42c10.167,6.531,20.333,13.063,30.5,19.596
        c-0.533-0.343,0.075-6.82,0.075-7.5c0-0.76,0.607-7.062-0.075-7.5C27.666,20.484,17.5,13.952,7.333,7.42
        c0.533,0.343-0.075,6.821-0.075,7.5C7.258,15.679,6.651,21.98,7.333,22.42L7.333,22.42z" />
        </g>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path fill="#C8C7C7" d="M67.667,7.419c-10.167,6.532-20.333,13.063-30.5,19.595c-0.682,0.438-0.075,6.74-0.075,7.5
        c0,0.68,0.608,7.157,0.075,7.5c10.167-6.531,20.333-13.063,30.5-19.595c0.683-0.438,0.075-6.741,0.075-7.5
        C67.742,14.24,67.134,7.762,67.667,7.419L67.667,7.419z" />
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Comment: I see how that works now. If you hover over the svg, the path will change it's fill to .. I'll accept this answer when the timers done. Thanks!

Comment: If you have more paths in your SVG, then wrap your paths around a `g` element, say `<g class="path-group">` and then `g.path-group:hover path { fill: red}`

Comment: @Duopixel Thanks! Forgot to mention that.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an extra group.  Just give the paths the same class: `svg:hover path.path-group`.  http://jsfiddle.net/6m8pd83q/1/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau But compare http://jsfiddle.net/6m8pd83q/1/ to http://jsfiddle.net/6m8pd83q/ .. in the latter example, the arrow only turns red when hovering over it. Whereas in the first example, the arrow turns red when hovering anywhere within the rectangular `svg` area.

Comment: How exactly the hover works is up to the OP.  I was just attempting to demonstrate that it is not necessary to wrap the paths in an extra group in order to get them to synchronize.